# Combining Grails Plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Can I combine the following plugins together or are there any incompatibilities?
How can I test if the plugins work well together?

```
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Why do you question this?  Are you getting errors?  Why do you think they cannot be combined?

Comment: @Michael J. Lee Because sometimes plugins does not work together.

Comment: Right... but please show a little more effort in your question

Answer (score 0):

The first four are all related since they're based on the http://grails.org/plugin/resources plugin, so you shouldn't have issues there. The versions will likely matter though.

The `cache` plugin is completely unrelated since it has nothing to do with static resources. It caches service and controller method calls, GSP fragments, and template content.